# A reviewer of my paper told me that "TABLES & FIGURES: too many and difficult to follow in text" What does this mean?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

A reviewer of my paper told me that "TABLES & FIGURES:  To many and difficult to follow in text.  Not optimized for readers"  What does this mean? What should I work on to improve my paper?

Answer (score 8):

It means what it says:

1. there are too many figures and tables
2. In the main text those are difficult to follow
3. It appears that they are not there for the reader.

So reduce the number of graphs and tables, and improve their discussion in the text.

Answer (score 1):

A paper should tell a story, where tables and figures are story-telling aids. They should convey your message effectively and reduce the dependency on the main text body; i.e. a reader should be able to understand your message more easily by looking at figures/tables than by simply reading the whole manuscript text.

Now, like any aid, these should be used appropriately. It is possible to overload the reader with information, and make him/her lose track of the central theme. Since visual tools are more striking than text, unwisely used figures can distract more than poorly written text.

In order to avoid such mistakes, I suggest doing the following; in this paper and beyond:

(1) Ask yourself if any table duplicates information already in the text. If so, remove the table.

(2) Question if any the information presented in figures and tables is *essential* to the paper. If not, consider removing them. Also see point 5.

(3) Check if each figure/table is mentioned in the text or not. Ensure that a reader has a fair idea about what the figure/table is about from the text, before (s)he actually sees the figure/table.

(4) Ensure that the figure/table captions are adequate and self-sufficient. A reader who sees the figure/table before reading about it in the text should be able to know what data is shown and what it represents, even if the significance is not clear. Scale bars, axis units and numbering (Fig. 1 (a) etc.) is essential.

(5) Avoid separate instances of similar figures/tables. If there are four graphs representing different stages of process A, see if they can be combined into a single graph. Colours, linestyles, multiple axes are your friends for graphs, as are inset images for other figures. If several similar tables exist and are essential, consider moving them into an appendix.